# How many distinct $6$ digit numbers are there in which all of the digits $1$ to $5$ appear?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations, combinations

[image]

For part (i), I think it's just $6!$.

(ii), I think if we treat $\texttt{123}$ as a block, then we should have 4 slots intead of 6 slots now, so the answer should be $4!$.

(iii) $\frac{6!}{2}$ - this should also be correct.

(iv) -not sure what do to- need help and explanation. I did some programming and checked one by one, and if my code is correct, the answer is `5280`?

Comment: Do we count leading zeros (e.g. $012345$) as a 6 digit number?

Comment: (i), (ii), and (iii) all appear to be correct.

Comment: I suspect that the allowed digits are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ for each part of the question, in which case $5280$ is far too large.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry for the confusion, I think in the last part, we allow all digits from 0 to 9, but we don't allow leading 0s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $5!$ ways to lay out the the digits $1$ to $5$ in positions ABCDE.

We need to insert a sixth digit.  There are $6$ positions we can place it (before the $A$, between the $A$ and the $B$, etc.....)

We need to insert a sixth digit.  The sixth digit could be $0$.  It could but $1...5$ or it could but $6,7,8,9$.  Each case has its issues.

If the sixth digit is $6,7,8,9$ there is no issue.  There are $4$ possible choice, $6$ positions, and $5!$ ways we did the $1...5$.  So $4\cdot 6\cdot 5!$ ways to do that.

If the sixth digit is $0$ the only issue is that we can't put it in the $1$ position.  SO there is $1$ choice of what digit $0$ could be (namely $0$) and $5$ positions to put it in and $5!$ ways to do the $1....5$.  So $5\cdot 5!$ ways to do it.

Now the issue with the sixth digit being $1....5$ is we are double counting.  There are $5!$ ways to place the $1$ through $5$.  And there are $6$ places to put the $6$th digit.  But wherever we put the second copy of the digit would be the same as though we had put it there originally and we put the second copy where the firs was.  So there are $5$ choices of the $6$th digit and $6$ places to put it but to take double counting into account; there are $5\times \frac {6\times 5!}2$ ways to do this.

So in total:

$4\cdot 6\cdot 5! +  5\cdot 5! + 5\cdot \frac {6\cdot 5!}2=$

$5!(4\cdot 6 + 5 + 5\times \frac 62) = 120\times (24+5+15)=120\times 44=5280$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming leading zeroes count as 6 digit numbers. Using the principle of inclusion-exclusion (PIE), we have:
$10^6$ ways without any restrictions,
$9^6$ ways without including $i_k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ as a digit for which there are $5 \choose 1$ combinations for $i_1$, $8^6$ ways without including $i_1$ nor $i_2$, for which there are $5 \choose 2$ combinations, $7^6$ ways without including $i_1$ nor $i_2$ nor $i_3$, for which there are $5 \choose 3$ combinations, $6^6$ ways without including $i_1$ nor $i_2$ nor $i_3$ nor $i_4$ for which there are $5 \choose 4$ combinations, and finally there are $5^6$ combinations not including any of the digits from $1$ through $5$.

Hence, the solution (including leading zeroes) is:

$$10^6 - {5 \choose 1}(9^6) + {5 \choose 2} (8^6) - {5 \choose 3}(7^6) + {5 \choose 4}(6^6)- 5^6 = 5400$$

If you do not count leading zeroes, subtract the number of combinations with leading zeroes, that being:

$
5400 - 5! = 5280
$

Comment: The digits are $1$ through $6$.  No zeroes.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's what I thought at first, until the OP posted his program produced a solution of $5280$. Plus the question just asks "How many 6 digit numbers are there in which the numbers 1 through 5 appear", not "In how many of these arranges does...", which would be expected language given the previous parts for the question, if it was asking solely for digits between 1 and 6.

Comment: Perhaps the second part allows for repeats or digits other than $1-6$.  Also, the code might not be correct.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well $5280$ is pretty far off from the number of solutions had only the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$ be used (that being $2520$). I think the question is worded pretty poorly then. Nonetheless, if you are correct, then my solution is almost valid, just need to switch around 10 to 6, 9 to 5, etc.

Comment: If we assume that the fourth question is related to the first three then the answer to "how many in which all the numbers 1 to 5 occur" has to be "all of them" or $6!$.  We are using each number once so the numbers 1 to 5 must occur.  ...  To my way or reasoning, I figure this must be a different question entirely.  "How many distinct six digit numbers are the in which digits 1 to 5 occur" must be $5280$... unless "distinct" six digit numbers (what's a *non*distinct six digit numbers) means the six digits are each distinct....

Comment: .... if the six digits must be distinct then there are $4*6*5! + 5*5!$ or $5*6*5!-5!$ ways to do it.... Okay... I agree it was poorly worded but I don't see how the fourth question can require that only the digits $1-6$ are used.